# Full address is not showing in the response

Tags: amazon-pay

I want full selected address when the user selects any address from the address book.

Following is the response what I got when "getOrderReferenceDetails" is executed.

```
{
"GetOrderReferenceDetailsResult": {
    "OrderReferenceDetails": {
        "OrderReferenceStatus": {
            "State": "Draft"
        },
        "Destination": {
            "DestinationType": "Physical",
            "PhysicalDestination": {
                "StateOrRegion": "IA",
                "City": "CLEAR LAKE",
                "CountryCode": "US",
                "PostalCode": "50428"
            }
        },
        "ExpirationTimestamp": "2018-01-01T12:51:02.920Z",
        "IdList": {

        },
        "SellerOrderAttributes": {
            "StoreName": "TEST1234"
        },
        "OrderTotal": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "Amount": "253.98"
        },
        "ReleaseEnvironment": "Sandbox",
        "SellerNote": "LEED Green Associate Exam Prep Online Anytime",
        "AmazonOrderReferenceId": "S01-2494539-9324741",
        "CreationTimestamp": "2017-07-05T12:51:02.920Z",
        "RequestPaymentAuthorization": "false"
    }
},
"ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "ffa51eb9-a31a-48d2-a2a5-b37126eba592"
},
"ResponseStatus": "200"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the entire shipping address prior to confirming an order, you need to take the following steps:

- Ensure the "payments:shipping_address" scope is requested in your Amazon Pay button code
- Capture the Access Token during the login process (this can be found appended to the return URL, or retrieved using Login with Amazon JS SDK)
- Pass the Access Token in to the GetOrderReferenceDetails API call via the AddressConsentToken field

If the above three actions are taken, you'll receive the full shipping address while the order is still in draft state. Below is an example response. Note it now contains the `AddressLine1`, `Name` and `Phone` fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<GetOrderReferenceDetailsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01">
  <GetOrderReferenceDetailsResult>
    <OrderReferenceDetails>
      <AmazonOrderReferenceId>P01-7416549-1234567</AmazonOrderReferenceId>
      <ExpirationTimestamp>2015-07-09T00:54:54.828Z</ExpirationTimestamp>
      <Constraints>
        <Constraint>
          <ConstraintID>AmountNotSet</ConstraintID>
          <Description>The seller has not set the amount for the Order Reference.</Description>
        </Constraint>
      </Constraints>
      <IdList/>
      <OrderReferenceStatus>
        <State>Draft</State>
      </OrderReferenceStatus>
      <Destination>
        <DestinationType>Physical</DestinationType>
        <PhysicalDestination>
          <Phone>2061112222</Phone>
          <PostalCode>98100-2000</PostalCode>
          <Name>John Doe</Name>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <StateOrRegion>WA</StateOrRegion>
          <AddressLine1>100 SEATTLE ST</AddressLine1>
          <City>SEATTLE</City>
        </PhysicalDestination>
      </Destination>
      <ReleaseEnvironment>Live</ReleaseEnvironment>
      <Buyer>
        <Email>john.doe@abc.com</Email>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
      </Buyer>
      <SellerOrderAttributes/>
      <CreationTimestamp>2015-01-10T00:54:54.828Z</CreationTimestamp>
    </OrderReferenceDetails>
  </GetOrderReferenceDetailsResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>e1de6c1f-64fd-48ec-9a69-a34646464</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetOrderReferenceDetailsResponse>
```